# Небольшой makefile

Tags: cmake, makefile, bash, linux

Всем привет! Пишу небольшой проект, но количество библиотек и прочих флагов при компиляции заставляет посмотреть в сторону `make`-файла. Строка компиляции у меня такая

```
nvcc -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/lib/mpich2/include/ -g -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -o main main.cu -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lmpi -lopa -lmpl -lrt -lcr -lpthread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

До этого особо дело с `make` файлами не имел, но приблизительно представляю, что это. В `make` файле мне нужно указать папку с исходниками, папку с заголовочными файлами, папку, в которую будет собираться бинарник, ну и указать использованные пути и либы при компиляции. Как хоть приблизительно будет выглядеть данный `makefile`? И чем отличается `make` от `cmake`? Что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, самый простой и примитивный вариант

```
LIBS_PATH = -L/usr/local/lib        -L/usr/lib
LIBS = -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lmpi -lopa -lmpl -lrt -lcr -lpthread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system  -lopencv_core  
INCLUDE_PATH = -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/lib/mpich2/include/
FLAGS = -g -O2
main: main.cu
    nvcc $(INCLUDE_PATH)  $(FLAGS)  -o $@ $^ $(LIBS_PATH) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Отлично! То, что мне нужно, только еще бы указать директорию с сорцами и директорию для бинарника, было бы вообще супер! Наверное на досуге стоит подробнее почитать про эти make файлы, в некоторых ситуациях очень удобная вещь.

Comment: А ещё советую посмотреть в сторону [tup](http://gittup.org/tup/), как на альтернативу `make`.